# Kubernetes custom action when readiness probe fails

Tags: kubernetes, autoscaling, readinessprobe

I am currently trying to scale automatically a deployment when the readiness probe hass failed for its pods currently running.

A pod is IDLE until a POST request is sent to it and while it is processing the request, it is not answering any other request.

To know when a processing is in progress, I created an endpoint returning TRUE if the pod is IDLE, FALSE otherwise.

I configure the readiness probe to query this endpoint to mark it as unavailable when a processing is in progress (and to mark it back to available when it is not processing anymore).

By default I have a limited pool of pods (like 5) that can answer requests.

But I still want to be able to send another POST with other parameters to trigger another processing when all my 5 pods are unavailable.

So, when the readiness probe fails for all pods, I want to scale the deployment in order to have other pods availbel to answer requests.

The issue here is that I did not find how to do such a thing with K8S or if this is even possible. Is there someone who could help me on this?

An alternative would be to create a 'watcher' pod who would watch all the readiness probe for a given deployement and when I fails for all pods, the watch would be in charge of scaling the deployement.

But this alternative implies development that I would like to avoid if it is natively possible to do in K8S.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

A readinessprobe by itself shouldn't be able to scale a deployment. By default, the only thing it can do is removing the Pod's IP from the endpoints of all the services that match the Pod.

The only solution that comes to my mind is what you said, so having an Horizontal Pod Autoscaler with custom metrics pointing to a Pod that keeps track of all the readinessprobes.

Comment: Yeah, that what I thought. Well I have resigned myself then, it won't be hard to do but I would have prefer to stay in a K8S managed style.
Thank you for your feedback :)